# Java Script. Как сделать, чтобы в цикле,если в промпт введено не число,он переспрашивал его,а не переходил на другой?

Tags: javascript

```
let firstYear;
let secondYear;

while(isNaN(parseFloat (firstYear && secondYear) ) && !isFinite(firstYear && secondYear) || (firstYear && secondYear) == `` || (firstYear && secondYear) == ` `) {
    firstYear = +prompt(`Начальный год`) ;
    secondYear = +prompt(`Конечный год`) ;
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Попробуйте сделать два отдельных цикла, в каждом по одному `prompt`

Upd. Если нужно иметь один цикл

Хорошо бы в переменных хранить уже числа.
В условии цикла `while` проверяйте, что обе переменных содержат значения.
Внутри цикла считывайте первое значение, сразу приводите его к числу. Второе значение считывайте только если первое значение считано верно, используйте `if`

Comment: C 2 циклами все работает,но нужно с 1)

Comment: А почему нужен один?

Comment: Ну вот задание такое:)Не могу решить

Comment: Ок, обновил ответ

Comment: @БорисЛуговкин, скорее всего ты просто не так понял задание